# cocos2d-x-2.2.6 Android integration

Tags: android, cocos2d-x-2.x

I'm using `cocos2d-x-2.2.6` and my app crashes, when `runnin` on a device.
logcat points me on Cocos2dxRenderer.java file and it crashes in

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(final GL10 pGL10, final EGLConfig pEGLConfig) {
     Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeInit(this.mScreenWidth, this.mScreenHeight);
     this.mLastTickInNanoSeconds = System.nanoTime();
}
```

on calling Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeInit(this.mScreenWidth, this.mScreenHeight);

**error is:**

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI FindClass called with pending exception 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError' thrown in void org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeInit(int, int):-2 in call to FindClass
```

What could be a reason of it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed it!
It was type convertation problem.